# How to create Google Cloud Logging entries that are correlated with the request log's trace ID?

Tags: go, logging, trace, google-cloud-run

Using the [Google Cloud Logging client library for go](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/go), it's possible to specify the `Trace` field on an `Entry` struct: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#log-entries. By default, on Cloud Run, requests are logged with a trace ID. How can I get this trace ID and specify it in the logs I create so I can correlate logs by the request that caused them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requests that come in to Cloud Run will have the header `X-Cloud-Trace-Context`. This header is actually `traceID/anotherID`. When you create a logs `Entry` with the `cloud.google.com/go/logging` package, you need to specify the `Trace` field in the format `projects/{$project_id}/traces/{$trace_id}` with your project ID and the trace ID from the header.

In my code, I get the trace ID from the request header and set it on the request context `c` like:

```golang
ctx := context.WithValue(c.Context(), logging.TraceId{}, c.Get("X-Cloud-Trace-Context"))
```

where `logging` is my own custom logging package. Then inside logging code, I have this method to attach a trace from a context to a Cloud logging entry:

```golang
func populateLogsEntryWithTrace(ctx context.Context, entry logging.Entry) logging.Entry {
    traceID, ok := ctx.Value(TraceId{}).(string)
    if ok {
        trace := strings.Split(traceID, "/")[0]
        entry.Trace = fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/traces/%s", projectID, trace)
    }
    return entry
}
```